# DownloadFileAsync on Android in Unity with Mono: NullReferenceException in WebRequestPrefixElement..ctor?

Tags: c#, android, .net, unity-game-engine, webclient

I'm trying to download something with **WebClient** and **DownloadFileAsync** in the **Unity3D** engine and it works on **Desktop**, I think on **iPhone** as well but it fails to do so on **Android**.

Basically this is what I do:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), path);
}
```

And this is the exception I get on my **Android 12**, Google Pixel 4a phone:

```
System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
08-18 18:12:20.138 26647 26666 I Unity   :   at System.Net.WebRequestPrefixElement..ctor (System.String P, System.Type creatorType) [0x00018] in <8bb5d2547dc749eeb8bd52a9eb3b67d1>:0
08-18 18:12:20.138 26647 26666 I Unity   :   at System.Net.WebRequest.PopulatePrefixList () [0x00040] in <8bb5d2547dc749eeb8bd52a9eb3b67d1>:0
08-18 18:12:20.138 26647 26666 I Unity   :   at System.Net.WebRequest.get_PrefixList () [0x00022] in <8bb5d2547dc749eeb8bd52a9eb3b67d1>:0
08-18 18:12:20.138 26647 26666 I Unity   :   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.Uri requestUri, System.Boolean useUriBase) [0x0002e] in <8bb5d2547dc749eeb8bd52a9eb3b67d1>:0
08-18 18:12:20.138 26647 26666 I Unity   :   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.Uri requestUri) [0x00014] in <8bb5d2547dc749eeb8bd52a9eb3b67d1>:0
08-18 18:12:20.138 26647 26666 I Unity   :   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest (System.Uri address) [0x00000] in <8bb5d2547dc749eeb8bd52a9eb3b67d1>:0
08-18 18:12:20.138 26647 26666 I Unity   :   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFileAsync (System.Uri address, System.String fileName, System.Object userToken) [0x00032] in <8bb5d2547dc749eeb8bd52a9eb3b67d1>
```

Could you help me investigating? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

This only seems to happen with **Mono** scripting backend. Now it works once I switched to **IL2CPP** and checked the ARM64 checkbox due to Unity's suggestion.

Comment: Did you checked "system.net/webRequestModules" config section? Maybe there is something there. Also, it seems it is picking non-mobile version of lib, which causes it to fallback into parsing config section rather than forcibly select [http/https/ftp/ftps]. See more here - https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/main/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/Net/WebRequest.cs Did you correctly built it for mobile environment?

Comment: @eocron what do you mean by checking? what should I look for there? :\ I'm unsure if I correctly built it for mobile. There are just a few checkboxes at the build panel, and they doesn't seem relevant in this issue. Or are they? :| I'm a bit clueless.

Comment: @eocron Now that I switched to IL2CPP, it works. But I prefer Mono because it takes ages to build with IL2CPP. Why is this issue happening with Mono?

Comment: For some reason its not seeing it as MOBILE. Try DefineConstants explicitly in project and see if it helps (im not particullary proficient with Unity3d way of compiling, but there should be a way to pick). Another way is to just add this config, so it would show up in *ConfigurationManager.GetSection ("system.net/webRequestModules")*. See more here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/webrequestmodules-element-network-settings

Comment: @eocron I can't really find a config other than the csproj file and only thing I could find is: <Reference Include="System.Net.Requests">. Where is this ConfigurationManager.GetSection?

Comment: Web.config, let it lay near your executable in binaries

Comment: I found 3 Web.configs in separate folders in MonoBleedingEdge/etc/mono/<dotnetversion: 2.0, 3.0, 4.0> but none of them contain "webRequestModules". (case insensitive) search.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `using` block which will call `.Dispose()` when exited. In the documentation for [`WebClient.DownloadFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?view=net-6.0) it states the following:

> Downloads, to a local file, the resource with the specified URI. This method does not block the calling thread.

This means you have a race condition and it's entirely possible that your `WebClient` object is being disposed before `DownloadFileAsync` gets a chance to do what it needs to do.

There's no indication in your post whether this code is executing in a coroutine, a synchronous function, or a task but you should either use [`DownloadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=net-6.0) which isn't async and will therefore block the thread and allow you to keep your `using` block or you can use the [`DownloadFileCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted?view=net-6.0) event to keep it async, get rid of the `using` block, and manually dispose the client when it's done.

I'll also add that, since you're using Unity, you might want to 1) look into using [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) as it's a bit more simplified API and 2) switch to building with IL2CPP.

Comment: I removed the using block, and added a Dispose in DownloadFileCompleted: client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, ev) => { Debug.Log("disposing web client"); client.Dispose(); }; And according to the log the null ref exception happens BEFORE the dispose debug text. So my guess is that it's not the WebClient that is null.

Comment: I've just switched to IL2CPP and it works. But don't know why my Android doesn't like Mono...

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
void DownloadFile()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler( DownloadFileCompleted );
    client.DownloadFileAsync ((new Uri (url, path));
}

void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        //Nice!
    }
}
```

Also if you can specify in your question which is your URL and Path,maybe the error is there, be sure they are consistent across OS, so your path is something like: Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "file.extension"

Comment: The error happens before DownloadFileCompleted is fired, so error checking at the callback wouldn't really help me fix why the download throws exception. Regarding Path and URL, there is a specific exception if the OS can't understand the path, so I don't think that that's the cause :\